# HeartBeat event in event driven microservice architecture?

Tags: microservices, event-driven-design

Is it a good idea to use HeartBeat events in Event-driven Microservice Architecture ?

The application i'm working on contains an Event Distribution Framework which collects events from various systems and publishes to the Consumer app.

I was wondering if event driven architecture talks anything about HeartBeat events to monitor e2e connectivity .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you will have additional tools in place for monitoring your services.

Having said that, messages exchanged (mostly that doesn't contain business logic such as heartbeats, ping-pongs etc.) is a common practice to monitor the connectivity between two isolated environments in particular where trust between is low.

Also sometimes these messages are also used to keep these connections alive, since not frequently used connections/ports usually closed to prevent memory leak.